# What's the difference between (typeof variable === 'boolean') and (typeof variable == 'boolean')?

Tags: javascript, comparison, typeof

I all,
I can't figure out - in type comparison/test - why we usually use :

```
typeof variable === 'boolean'
```

...and never see this one :

```
typeof variable == 'boolean'
```

As it seems to me that typeof always returns a string value (the type name), I don't understand why we should test the type... of the type string ?

Comment: It is a known good practice to always use `===`, it makes no difference here.

Comment: you can see the difference if you check '2' == 2 and '2' === 2. the 3 = signs make a typecheck too

Comment: Without seeing any reasons for why `===` should be used over `==`, it's impossible to say whether they are convincing or not. In the vast majority of cases (including this one) it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just common practice, and it's idiomatic because triple equals compares the types as well; which makes more sense since you're interested in the type. But in practice you aren't going to see a difference in behaviour in this case. Also see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: The type being compared by `===` here has nothing to do with the type of the value being tested by *typeof*, so not really "idiomatic".